# really slow shutdown

Tags: shutdown, 23.04

3 days ago I bought a new intel 13700 machine & installed a fresh copy of 23.04.
However I find that shutting down takes a really long time (90 sec), while my 6700K machine only takes about 4-5 seconds with 23.04 on it.

What seems to be happening is shutting down proceeds quickly when I choose the option.
The screen turns black and shows the logo for my motherboard 'Tuf Gaming' plus the ubuntu logo and for 3 seconds, the processing circle.

Then the processing circle disappears and nothing happens for nearly a minute and a half.
No SSD light is flashing on the case, so I can't see anything happening.

Is there a shutdown log that might help me here? or some other diagnostic?

It is strange as startup only takes about 2-3 seconds.

Comment: There are logs in the `/var/log` directory that may shed light on the issue. One question is whether there are any network-connected mounts. Mounted Samba connections can sometimes take a while to disconnect if there are open files or caches that need to be flushed.

Comment: I do make network connections on occasion to a NAS, but they terminate on reboot.
I managed  to find something about pressing 'Esc' on the shutdown and it showed that the system is waiting on a process called 'crond'.   So now I have something to go on.

Comment: how do I award credit to matigo for their comment?

Comment: @matigo - I can't seem to find an up arrow next to your comment.

Comment: sadly the only triangles I'm seeing are for my initial question and my answer... none for any 'comments'. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it.
After the 'crond' discovery, I found an offsite solution that recommended running bleachbit in 'root' mode.

I needed to reboot twice after running bleachbit, but now my shutdown is so fast that I have no time to press 'esc'.

I also enabled Total Memory Encryption, but I think that had no effect.
I'll undo that.